# Printing 5 words that last 3 letters are the same in Python

Tags: python

My program should read the content of a text file and find similar words according to the last 3 characters and print out 5 of these similar words in any order. For ex: warm, arm, charm...

I write a code but I could not complete.

```
def main():
    # An empty array
    my_dict = {}

    with open("words.txt", "r") as f:
        for line in f:

            for word in line.strip().split(" "):
                s = word[-3:]
                if s not in my_dict:
                    # add 3 letters as the key
                    my_dict[s] = []
                my_dict[s].append(word)

                if len(my_dict[s]) == 5:
                    print(my_dict[s])
                    return

        # this will only print if there are no 3 words with the same start letters
    print(my_dict)
print(main())
```

My output is

```
{'ger': ['finger'], 'iss': ['premiss'], 'arm': ['arm'], 'ike': ['like']}
```

Comment: `if len(my_dict[s]) == -3:` should be `5`.

Comment: @tevemadar I fixed. Thanks

Comment: Why `-`? You want it to print when there are 5 elements available for the given key.

Comment: Also, the `append` should not be indented.

Comment: If you have fixed this, please do not update the question. Add an answer, showing how you fixed it, so that it might help future readers.

Answer (score 1):

Putting together:

```
def main():
    # An empty array
    my_dict = {}

    with open("words.txt", "r") as f:
        for line in f:

            for word in line.strip().split(" "):
                s = word[-3:]
                if s not in my_dict:
                    # add 3 letters as the key
                    my_dict[s] = []
                my_dict[s].append(word)

                if len(my_dict[s]) == 5:
                    print(my_dict[s])
                    return

    # this will only print if there are no 3 words with the same start letters
    print(my_dict)
print(main())
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
#VARIABLES
end_letters = [] ;
word_list = [] ;

#openning the file
file = open("words.txt","r");

#obtaining all last 3 letters and adding then to list but skip if the 3 letters already exist

for words in file:
    #adding words to word_list
    word_list.append(words);
    #checking if the last 3 letters already exist
    if words[-4::] not in end_letters:
        #append list with words's  last three letters
        end_letters.append(words[-4::]);

#closing file
file.close();

#using end_letters list , print the words from word_list with their last 3 letters the same as the end_letters
for criteria in end_letters:
    for words in word_list:
        if (words[-4:] == criteria):
            print(words);
```